# setting base path for sub-directories script in php

Tags: php

I may know that this question leads to a no-answer-topic  but who knows ! :D

concider we have a php script that should be used in root path

like this :

```
root/
```

but when we move it to a sub folder its like this :

```
root/script/gallery
```

in its codes,its noted that

```
images/add.png
```

and it should be

```
scripts/gallery/images/add.png
```

ok one way is setting base path in  section

```
<base href="http://localhost/scripts/gallery/" />
```

but setting this base path makes other scripts located in root directory to be failed .

easy solution and laboring way is to change all paths in the scripts .

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this. The path is from your htdocs root.

```
if(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == '/script/dir/gallery')
{
  echo '<base href="http://localhost/scripts/gallery/" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but when we move it to a sub folder its like this :

Anything that is likely to change is a good candidate for abstraction. I myself have a quite simple URL class which determines the currently requested URL by using the $_SERVER superglobal, and it has a simple method which can create URL's from the base URL, including relative paths.

So, instead of

```
<img src="/images/foo.jpg" />
```

I use

```
<img src="<?php echo url( './images/foo.jpg' ); ?>
```

When I relocate the PHP files, all paths are automatically updated.